# MYSQL Multiple COUNT() With Single Query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want to get total ROW types with single query. Let me explain it.

Normally I use this query to get one of them:

```
$database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM workers WHERE job = 1");
$totalWorkers = $database->fetchObject()->c;
```

So, it works flawless but there 7 more job types (0-8). This is just (1).

I can do like that: [TOO MUCH QUERY TO EXECUTE, NOT GOOD]

```
$database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM workers WHERE job = 1");
$totalWorkers1 = $database->fetchObject()->c;

$database->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM workers WHERE job = 2");
$totalWorkers2 = $database->fetchObject()->c;
```

But I don't want to execute these multiple queries, is there any easy way to do that? I want to get results of count like that:

```
$totalWorkers2 = $database->fetchObject()->type_1;
$totalWorkers2 = $database->fetchObject()->type_2;
```

I've searched it everywhere but I couldn't find & think any logic for that ...

Comment: I know, there is very easy way to do that, but I can't think about it.

Comment: `SELECT job, COUNT(*) as c FROM workers group by job` ?

Comment: How can I get result of it? $database->fetchObject()-> ...

Comment: Why do it with a single query?  Get it working first, optimize the critical sections later.

Comment: I always optimize my queries because there are like 1,5 million records......

Comment: I have to optimize it.

Comment: Only 1.5M records? Sounds like a small database. I doubt you'd see much time taken with the second run as the database would be cached at that point.

Comment: I don't know about you, but 1.5M records are huge for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(IF(job=1,1,0)) as job1count, sum(IF(job=2,1,0)) as job2count FROM workers;
```

Or

```
SELECT job, count(*) as c FROM workers where job in (1,2) GROUP BY job;
```

Depending if you want them in the same record or not

Comment: Good idea on the first example to align with the requested results from the OP

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much sir. That was really really good answer! And quick!

Comment: The first query could be simplified: `SELECT SUM(job = 1), SUM(job = 2) ...`

Comment: @shmosel, `SUM(job = 1)` can return `NULL` instead of `0` if no row with `job=1` exists.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, `job = 1` evaluates to 0 (aka `FALSE`) if `job` is any value other than 1 or `NULL`. So your statement is only correct if all values are `NULL`, or if there are no results at all (in which case any `SUM()` variation will return `NULL`). Of course if that's an issue, just do `IFNULL(SUM(...), 0)`.

Comment: @shmosel, you're right - my mistake. Don't know what i thought - I'm using that shortcut too.

Answer (score 0):

You can group results by job

```
$database->query("SELECT job, COUNT(*) as c FROM workers WHERE job in (1,2) group by job");

$tmp = $database->fetchAll();

$result = array();

foreach ($tmp as $o) $result[$o->job] = $o->c;
```

And then use array `$result` as `$result[1]` for job=1, `$result[2]` for job=2

You can remove filter by job `WHERE job in (1,2)` if you need counts for all jobs